# Matching dates with Regex inside of a random string

Tags: java, regex, string, date

I am trying to do this in `Java`:

I receive this kind of string

```
"12/07/2004dddsss12/10/2010ñrrñrñr10/01/2000ksdifjsdifffffdd04/04/1998"
```

Then I have to find one or more dates inside that string, date format: `dd/mm/yyyy`

Finally I have to copy to another string dates matched: `"12/07/2004 12/10/2010 10/01/2000 04/04/1998"`

PD: I'm using this website `http://regexpal.com/` to test if works. I tried some website **regex** and anyone worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the validity of the date with the extracted content.

To extract the dates:

```
String regex = "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}";
```

Check here at fiddle: http://fiddle.re/fa0bf

Code:

```
 String input = "12/07/2004dddsss12/10/2010ñrrñrñr10/01/2000ksdifjsdifffffdd04/04/1998";
    String regex = "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Gives,

```
12/07/2004
12/10/2010
10/01/2000
04/04/1998
```